# jQuery prepend domain to text input

Tags: jquery

I have a domain (e.g: example.tld), and I want to allow users to create an e-mail address on this domain by only having to input the first half of the e-mail address. So the domain will be appended to the text box, and when the user clicks on the box the cursor will be at the start of the input field allowing them to enter their name.

Perferrably I would also like the domain value within the text input to be non-editable.

So when the page loads, I want the text box to look like:

```
<input type="text" id="emailaddress" value="@example.tld" />
```

Then when the user clicks, and starts entering text it'll look like; with the @example.tld" part being forced.

```
<input type="text" id="emailaddress" value="userenteredtext@example.tld" />
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just set the **@example.tld** outside of the input box ? since that is the functionality you try to mimic..

**Update**

as @bobince says in his comment, you would be better off just dealing with the possible user error (*submitting a whole email*) yourself, once he submitted the info or left the email field.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now, and it does work. I am now just trying to add some "bling" to the application. I've noticed on a few UI test runs that some users try to submit "user@example.tld" into the text box, even with the domain printed just to the side and the email address get's submitted as user@example.tld@example.tld. So just trying to be a little more user friendly and obvious as what is going on.

Comment: I'd just detect and deal with the error condition, automatically strip off the `@...` trailer on submission.